# How to verify my email address on Stack Exchange sites (e,g. Super User) or check its verification status?

Tags: support, email

On Super User I changed my email address under Email Settings. It sent me a verification link:

> "Confirm your email address - Super User".

When I click the button [Confirm your email address] under  "please confirm using the button" in the message , it says:

> "The link you used is too old, please use the verify email screen again to re-verify"

But where is the "verify email screen"?

How can I re-send a verification link?

Actually do I need to do it at all?

How can I see whether my address still  needs verification at all or it is verified already?